# How do I instrument a C program containing macros

Tags: macros, clang, instrumentation

I am trying to instrument all the if statements in a C program. For example

```
if(condition)
   statement1;
else
   statement2;
```

is instrumented to

```
if(condition)
{
   statement1;
}
else
{
   statement2;
}
```

I have the following code for instrumentation

```
void MyRecursiveASTVisitor::InstrumentStmt(Stmt *s)
{
    // Only perform if statement is not compound
    SourceLocation ST = s->getLocStart();
    if (!isa<CompoundStmt>(s)) {
        //insert an opening brace if not present
        Rewrite.InsertText(ST, "{\n", true, true);
        ST = s->getLocEnd();
        ST = ST.getLocWithOffset(1);
        Rewrite.InsertText(ST, "\n}\n", true, true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works fine for almost all of the cases. However, in the case when the statement is a MACRO expansion

```
else
    WARN((stderr,"%s: %s is a directory -- ignored\n", progname, ifname));
```

I get an assertion failure

```
Assertion `0 && "Invalid SLocOffset or bad function choice"' failed.
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Is there some special case for handling macros in clang?

Comment: What is `WARN` defined as? Is it under your control?

Comment: It is a #define in the program. I can not preprocess the program to remove the macros because that leads to a elimination of all dynamically defined macros.

Comment: Show us the definition of it.